# How do i add .ttf font to my Azure node.js app service project

Tags: node.js, azure-web-app-service

I have a node.js project and i am having issues with Chart.js fonts not showing when i deploy to azure app service (which is hosted on linux ubuntu 18) . here are my project files . and i wanted to know how to i import the .ttf fonts into my Node.js app so that it can be used on the remote app . Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue by registering the new .ttf fonts into my node.js code . here is the sample code :

```
const chartJSNodeCanvas = new ChartJSNodeCanvas({ width, height, chartCallback: (ChartJS) => {
// Just example usage
ChartJS.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'VTKS UNAMOUR';} });
chartJSNodeCanvas.registerFont('./testData/VTKS UNAMOUR.ttf', { family: 'VTKS UNAMOUR' });
```